# Alarmmanager sending SMS broadcast receiver not called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, sms

I have a single **Activity** (called as **NMessageActivity**) that has a simple method of **sending SMS**. Just using this code:

```
public void sendSMS(MBean dBean) {

    if (sentSMS != null && deliveredSMS != null) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(dBean.getToInNumbers(), null,
                dBean.getMessage(), sentSMS, deliveredSMS);
    } else {
        ToastObject.postMessage("Error code 233!");
    }

}
```

Before that, i did initialize the **Pending Intents** that I use. i put them on the **onCreate method** i have:

```
smsSentReceiver = new SentReceiver(this);
smsDeliveredReceiver = new DeliveredReceiver(this);
```

and then I register them at **onResume()**:

```
super.onResume();
registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter(TAG_SENT));
registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(TAG_DELIVERED));
```

and at **onPause()** I unregister them:

```
super.onPause();
unregisterReceiver(smsSentReceiver);
unregisterReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver);
```

And before sending the SMS, I do preparing the **AlarmManager** to execute the intent
after 2 seconds. Using this code:

```
    MBean dbbean = new MBean(txt_destNum.getText().toString(), txt_date
            .getText().toString(), txt_time.getText().toString(),
            MBean.STATUS_WAIT, txt_msg.getText().toString());

    db.addMBean(dbbean);

    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(TAG_SENT);
    Intent intentAlarm2 = new Intent(TAG_DELIVERED);

    // putting the values in
    intentAlarm.putExtra(MBean.MBEAN_NAME, dbbean.toString());

    sentSMS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    deliveredSMS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intentAlarm2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int sec = 2;

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (sec * 1000), sentSMS);
```

The problem is not on the above method and nor the AlarmManager. 
Instead, the problem is on the BroadcastReceiver that i Have. 
The Broadcast receivers are never called. Why is that happened?

Here are the Broadcast Receiver class in details:

**SentReceiver.java**

```
public class SentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MBean dBean;
    private Context dCont;
    private ToastSender dToast;
    private Activity dNMessageActivity;

    public SentReceiver(Activity obAct){
        dNMessageActivity = obAct;
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        ((NMessageActivity)dNMessageActivity).sendSMS(dBean);
    }

    private void vibratePhone() {

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) dCont
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        dToast = new ToastSender(arg0);
        dCont = arg0;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            // SMS has been sent
            dBean = new MBean(arg1.getStringExtra(MBean.MBEAN_NAME));

            vibratePhone();
            sendMessage();

            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            // Generic Failure

            dToast.postMessage("Error code 48!");

            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            // No Service

            dToast.postMessage("Error code 53!");

            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            // Null PDU

            dToast.postMessage("Error code 58!");

            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            // Radio Off

            dToast.postMessage("Error code 63!");

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

and another receiver is

**DeliveredReceiver.java**

```
public class DeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private ToastSender dToast;
    private Context dCont;
    private Activity dNMessageActivity;

    public DeliveredReceiver(Activity obAct){
        dNMessageActivity = obAct;
    }

    private void vibratePhone() {

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) dCont
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        dCont = arg0;
        dToast = new ToastSender(arg0);

        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            dToast.postMessage("SMS Sent");

            vibratePhone();

            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            dToast.postMessage("SMS Pending");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I wonder is that the Broadcast Receiver problem or the Pending Intent problem that  I passed over the Alarmmanager? Why the program doesnt call the Broadcast Receiver at all?

Comment: Do you have that broadcast receiver declared in AndroidMenifest.xml?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you're trying to do with the alarm you're setting?

Comment: @user3225831, for sure We dont need the declaration under AndroidManifest.xml if we do the Registering via code (programatically), isn't true? 
Well, Mike, I want the alarm could send the sms after couple seconds. But the Broadcast listener seems never called.

Comment: The PendingIntent you're creating for the alarm isn't going to send a message. You're creating it with an Intent for the `TAG_SENT` action, which, if it works at all, is only going to broadcast to the `smsSentReceiver`. (Btw, you have to use my @name, or I won't see your comments.)

Comment: of course it will go to the smsSentReceiver broadcast. That's why i put the sendMessage() method written over there. Check the switch case. Well, sorry i'll then use your name now @MikeM....

Comment: Ok, yeah, I didn't notice the `sendMessage()` method. Your design's a little convoluted, then. That Receiver should just be used for Sent confirmations, not triggering the actual send. If you just want to delay the send for a couple of seconds, there's no need to use an alarm. If you really do want to set an alarm, then you'll need to create a Receiver for an alarm action that initiates the send independently of the Sent confirmation Receiver.

Comment: Also, have you debugged to see if `onReceive()` is being called at all? If you're just going by the fact that a message doesn't get sent, and the device doesn't vibrate, then I would say that it's because there is no result code being set on the Intent you're broadcasting, and of the switch cases are being reached.